# Split an array in two differents objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a const `teams`. I want to split this `array`  into two `array` . The first team should be the team without a number in the first character of the name, and the second team should be with numbers in the first character of the team.

```
const [teams, setTeam] = useState([]);
const teams = [{id: 1, name: "1-First"},
               {id: 2, name: "Winner"},
               {id: 3, name: "2-Second"}]

// teamsWithNumber 
var myArray = teams.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.name.match('/^[A-Z0-9]/i')
});
const teamsWithNumber = myArray;
// teamsWithOUTNumber 
var myArray = teams.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.name!== obj.name.match('/^[A-Z0-9]/i')
});
const teamsWithOUTNumber = myArray;
```

My output is

```
// console.log(teamsWithOUTNumber)
[OUT] []
```

My desired output

```
teamsWithOUTNumber = [id: 2, name: "Winner"}]
teamsWithNumber = [{id: 1, name: "1-First"},
                   {id: 3, "2-Second"}]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what doesn't work. A [mre] is required.

Comment: Also, `{id: 3, "2-Second"}` isn't valid syntax

Comment: Looks like you're dealing with arrays, not objects.

Comment: Get a regular expression tutorial and try to understand what `/^[A-Z0-9]/i` does.

Comment: `obj.name!== obj.name.match('/^[A-Z0-9]/i')` will always be `true`

Comment: You do not need to wrap the regex in quotes. Have you tried running `"1-First".match('/^[A-Z0-9]/i')`? It returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?
I changed filters returned values.

```
const [teams, setTeam] = useState([]);
const teams = [{id: 1, name: "1-First"},
               {id: 2, name: "Winner"},
               {id: 3, name: "2-Second"}]

// teamsWithNumber 
var myArray = teams.filter(function (obj) {
        return !/^[-]?\d+$/.test(obj.name[0]);
});
const teamsWithNumber = myArray;
// teamsWithOUTNumber 
var myArray = teams.filter(function (obj) {
        return !/^[-]?\d+$/.test(obj.name[0]);
});
const teamsWithOUTNumber = myArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of RegExp seems to have a few fundamental flaws - you may find it helpful to use a utility like [Regex101](https://regex101.com) to assist with a more plain-English explanation of what your pattern does. For the one you've provided above, the tool specifically states:

> - `^` asserts position at start of a line
> - Match a single character present in the list below `[A-Z0-9]`
>
>   - `A-Z` matches a single character in the range between `A` (index `65`) and `Z` (index `90`) (case sensitive)
>   - `0-9` matches a single character in the range between `0` (index `48`) and `9` (index `57`) (case sensitive)

Since you've opted to wrap the RegExp literal in quotes, you've also inadvertently included the `/` characters as well, which none of the data you're testing against contains. As such, both patterns of data in `obj.name` will *never* match this pattern each time (with and without the leading digit-hyphen combination), leading to the results you're seeing.

Instead, tailor the pattern to express exactly what you're expecting to filter into each array. I've provided `/^\d-/` below, which explicitly matches strings beginning with a leading digit followed by a hyphen. This should more closely match what you seem to be going for.

Somewhat tangentially, since you're not trying to extract any data in this scenario, you should also opt for [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) over [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Finally, you can make your code meet your reuqirements *and* a bit more succinct by running `filter` on the same original array and storing the result into two separate variables - one operation to filter those that *do*  conform to the pattern `^\d-` (`teamsWithNumber`), and those that do not (`teamsWithOUTNumber`):

```js
const teams = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "1-First"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Winner"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "2-Second"
  }
]

const teamsWithNumber = teams.filter(obj => /^\d-/.test(obj.name));
const teamsWithOUTNumber = teams.filter(obj => /^(?!\d-)/.test(obj.name));
console.log(teamsWithNumber, teamsWithOUTNumber);
```

Comment: Another issue is they have quotes around the regex.

Answer (score 0):

`.match('/^[A-Z0-9]/i')` will not work, the `RegExp` literal is a string: use `.match(/^[A-Z0-9]/i)`.

Actually, you only need to test for `/^\d/` (the first character of the string to test is a number). Check [RegExp @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

You can use a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) using that test, something like

```js
const teams = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "1-First"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Winner"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "2-Second"
  }
];
const [numbered, notNumbered] = teams
  .reduce(([t1, t2], val) => 
    [...[t1, t2], /^\d/.test(val.name) ? t1.push(val) : t2.push(val)], [ [], [] ]);

console.log(`with number: ${
  JSON.stringify(numbered)}, \nno number: ${
  JSON.stringify(notNumbered)}`);
```